# Trying to add up hours in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an `IF` formula adding up the hours in my rota: `=IF(AC5>AB5, AC5-AB5,AC5+1-AB5)`, but in the total hours column, the addition isn't working.

A different site said to multiple it by 24. Neither has worked: `=(SUM(G5,K5,O5,S5,W5,AA5,AE5))x24` or `=(AE6+AA6+W6+S6+O6+K6+G6)`

I have tried editing the custom formula to be either `h:mm` or `[h]:mm` which also isn't working.

I have tried a sum formula also, but it is now a simple `=1+2+3`, etc.

[Rota screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3gZt.png)

[Rota Master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL5c3.png)

Comment: What does the statement "the addition isn't working" mean in this context. Is the result just the printed formula, is there an error message, is the cell left blank, or are you just getting an unexpected result? If possible, provide an example: supply us with the values of AC5 and AB5, and the result that you see if AC5>AB5, as well as a different example where AB5>AC5.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. To add a screenshot, (on Win10 you can use Win+Shift+S to take a screenshot which is copied to the clipboard) and then edit your post https://superuser.com/posts/1571525/edit and simply paste the image in the location you want it to go in the post. It will make it much easier to help you if we can see what your data look like.

Comment: Please refer to "[Add or subtract time](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-subtract-time-16aa6697-6d6e-49c1-8e2c-3398a7cad6ad?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)".

Comment: The answer to the formula is entirely incorrect. For example, If one persons rota is as follows:- OFF/9:00-21:00/09:00-19:00/OFF/10:00-22:00/10:00-22:00/09:00-19:00 the total hours next to each day uses the IF formula mentioned and is correct (i.e. 0/12/10/0/12/12/10) however, in the total column where it is adding up these total shift hours the answer (which should be 56) is 0. Another example where the total hours should be 50, the answer is 4.08. @VividKraig

Comment: @Emily the problem I have is the actual addition of time in the rota is fine, I know how to do it. When it comes to adding those totals together is where it goes wrong...

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, date and time is treated in a special way. Once you enter a value in a format that is recognized by Excel as a date or time format, it will be displayed as such and will help you automatically with adding / subtracting in a natural way - just as you tried doing (=SUM(A1:A3) will just some up the hours).

Time should be inserted in the format `[h]:[m]` - [h] representing hours, [m] minutes. And, you could also enter seconds if you'd like, like this: `[h]:[m]:[s]`.

For an example, I've entered 3 time values and summed them up just below them:

[image]

P.S: When entering a value in time/date format, excel actually stores a numeric value - each integer represents a whole day (starting from 1/1/1900) and the fraction represents the time of the day, so 10:00 will have the value of 10/24 (~0.42). You can see it by yourself, by entering a date or time and [changing its cell format](https://www.excel-easy.com/basics/format-cells.html) afterwards.